# Unidentified values appearing in my javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm creating a small game and I have a peace of code that collects the pressed keys during an interval of time.

```
var pressedKeys = [];

setTimeout(function() {
     for(var i = 0; i < pressedKeys.length; i++)
     alert("Time is up you have inputed " + pressedKeys[i] + " length " + pressedKeys.length);
}, 3000);

$(document).keydown(function(evt) {
    var key = evt.keyCode;
if (pressedKeys.length < 1) {
    pressedKeys[0] = key;
} else {
    pressedKeys[pressedKeys.length + 1] = key;
}
});
```

I'm new to javascript and I can't understand why I have unidentified values in the array. The funny thing to me is if I do the loop with a foreach I do not get the unidentified values.

Can some one please explain this to me. I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This...

```
pressedKeys[pressedKeys.length + 1] = key;
```

should be this...

```
pressedKeys[pressedKeys.length] = key;
```

---

Since Array indices are zero-based, the current last item in the Array will be its `length - 1`, which means the next item to fill will be the one at its `.length`.

---

You can actually get rid of the `if` statement...

```
$(document).keydown(function(evt) {
    pressedKeys[pressedKeys.length] = evt.keyCode;
});
```

It starts off with a `.length` of `0`, so the first entry will be at index `0`, which makes the `.length` equal to `1`, so the next entry will be at index `1`, and so on...

Comment: `pressedKeys.push(key)` would be even better.

Comment: @Rocket: It's an option, but how is it better?

Comment: Why get the `length` property, and then add to the array at that position when you can just say "add to the end"?

Comment: @Rocket: Because by getting the `.length` property, and adding to the array at that position, it *is* saying "add to the end". :)

Comment: And hear I was expecting a deep answer on the mechanics of java script. How nooby of me. Thanks you. :)

Comment: @JustmeVSI: You'll get no such depth from me.  ;o) You're welcome.

Comment: @Rocket: Different browsers will usually have different optimizations.  Chrome is so crazy fast that I'd rather optimize for the one(s) that need it. Before I made any serious decisions, I'd need to test older  Firefox and IE.

Comment: @Rocket: `.push()` has a negative psychological impact on me, like someone is trying to *push* me into doing something. Whereas `.length` makes me feel as though someone is going to great *lengths* on my behalf. This is how I make most of my coding decisions. :D

Answer (score 2):

Because of this:

```
} else {
    pressedKeys[pressedKeys.length + 1] = key;
}
```

The length property returns the length of an array. Arrays are zero-based, so when you refer to the `length`th index, you're referring to an non-existent element.
When you add an element at position `length + 1`, you're creating a gap between the last existing and new element.

This happens:

```
var pressedKeys = [];
var length = pressedKeys.length; // Equal to zero, 0
pressedKeys[length + 1] = key;   // Inserts key at position 0 + 1 = 1
// result: pressedKeys = [undefined, key]
```

To solve the issue, don't add `+1`, or use the [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method:

```
pressedKeys.push(key);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pressedKeys[pressedKeys.length + 1] = key;
```

This will actually skip elements.  Arrays are zero-indexed.

Let's say you have 3 elements in the array, they will be:

- `pressedKeys[0]`
- `pressedKeys[1]`
- `pressedKeys[2]`

When that line is ran `pressedKeys.length` will be 3, thus inserting the value into `pressedKeys[4]`.  This will make `pressedKeys[3]` undefined.

The line should be `pressedKeys[pressedKeys.length] = key`, or better yet, don't use the length, just [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) onto the array.

```
$(document).keydown(function(evt) {
    var key = evt.keyCode;
    pressedKeys.push(key); // this will add to the end of the array,
                           // no need to calculate the position
});
```